How to bundle TypeScript types in single file?
I am creating a package with TypeScript so in my dist folder I want to have only two files: index.js for the minified library itself and index.d.ts for types.
Normally, running tsc will generate an .d.ts file for every js file in my src folder, so my dist folder will be flooded with tons of typing files and one index.js file.
But Typescript supports bundling all types in one file via outFile option: outFile: dist/index.js with emitDeclarationOnly will create only one index.d.ts file where every js file from sources will be represented as declare module ...:
declare module "IBlockMeta" {
    // ...
}
declare module "product" {
    // ...
}

// And finally the index module AKA types for index.js file

declare module "index" {
    // ...
}

Now I specify exports in package.json:
"exports": {
    ".": {
        "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
        "import": "./dist/index.js"
    }
},

The problem is that on production side bundled types builded with outFile option are not recognised saying that index.d.ts is not a module!
Removing outFile option and generating all .d.ts files works just fine.
Why is this happening and is there a way to place all types in one file?

This may or may not be an answer to your question so I'm posting it as a comment, but you can always use a bundler like webpack/rollup/etc...
